# Google Sheet Split from 24:00 forcing to 24:00:00.000

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to work this out, can't find a solution.

The string, after REGEXEXTRACT is 20:00 24:00 25:00

I've been banging my head for hours, trying ways to convert, after the split, to get this result:

20:00
24:00
25:00

But it turns out that Google Sheets always forces:

20:00
24:00:00
25:00:00

Tried converting to text, using arrayformula, formatting cell as custom date, etc. Nothing has worked, so far.

Here a sheet example, already with the SPLIT result and the desired result.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12VISJZCSehTax8IJ88H4fmQ7Yoit6hENaI2WD_Sb2y8/edit?usp=sharing

Any clues?

Thanks! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited D14:F14 to get the result you want. You just needed to set the format for the output range to durations not military time:

**Format > Number > Custom number format** > *[h]:mm*

Answer (score 0):

you can force it:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT(SPLIT(D10; " "); {"[h]:mm"\ "[h]:mm"\ "[h]:mm"}))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I didn't found this idea before. I tried HH:MM but without sucess.